# Single word for a person who gets depressed when a certain activity or period comes to an end

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm a person who gets depressed when a holiday/school year is over. I've been looking for single word that gets the whole point over. If anyone would have any idea for a word that could express the title exactly, I'd be very grateful!

Comment: You mean, like every other normal person, you feel upset that vacation is over? I'm surprised!

Comment: I agree, the word you're looking for is **human**.

Comment: Not always. Sometimes, I'm extremely happy that a vacation is over. A word you should look into is Diversity, pal. ;)

Comment: You may say that a person affected by post work depression syndrome is "mentally  depleted".

Comment: Please enlighten me. Why are the words "holiday" and "school" hyphenated? Don't most kids RELISH the idea of school being over (assuming they'll then be on summer break)?

Answer (score 2):

**Downcast** — [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/downcast)

> *adjective* 1. Low in spirit; dejected

*"It was the end of his summer vacation and he became increasingly downcast at the prospect of returning to the drudgery of his low-paid office job in the city".*

May I also suggest that the OP reconsider the use of the word "depressed" in this context and in the 21st century. To be depressed nowadays is often understood to mean that one is suffering from [clinical depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Major_depressive_disorder), a mild-to-serious mental illness that requires medication (anti-depressants) and/or hospitalization. I think the public's awareness of the incidence and potential seriousness of "depression" has grown in the last 20-years, so that the word's benign use years ago has now changed to take on a medical state of mental illness.

Comment: +1 especially for your brief note about "clinical depression".

Comment: Thank you, and yes, I also suffer from a tangent of clinical depression. I've researched it a couple of times, and I've been also informed that all of the required symptoms match. I don't have the best past, just so ya know. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are just ***missing*** that period or activity (probably because you developed a strong liking for it).

[Miss](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/miss) (M-W):

> *transitive verb*
>
> 2:  to discover or feel the absence of

Answer (score 2):

I get what you are saying.  When I leave a job I miss everything, when I leave a house, or school, or anywhere, I miss it, even if it wasn't great.
We are NOSTALGIC.

From the [Oxford Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nostalgia):

> nostalgia- a sentimental longing or wistful affection for the past, typically for a period or place with happy personal associations

Comment: Nostalgic. Good word!

Comment: Your original post was plagiarism. I have proposed an edit to fix this, but in the future, you should be sure to cite things properly.

Answer (score 1):

How about ***glum*** and ***sullen***?

*Glum* -  Sullen, frowning; having an air of dejection or displeasure, esp. in phr. to look glum (OED).

*Sullen* - Characterized by, or indicative of, gloomy ill-humour or moody silence (OED).

Answer (score 1):

**Single word for a person who gets depressed when a certain activity or period comes to an end?**

I'm afraid there is no such a word. Just imagine if we had a single word for everyone who gets depressed by different life-events: putting on weight, breaking up one's marriage, losing one's parent, death of a pet, etc. Any suggestion we offered would be nonspecific, and could also be applied to the situations I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

How about **drained**, **depleted**, **down**, or **blue**?

For example:

> "After finishing any major project (activity, effort, etc.), I always feel
> **drained**."
>
> "After finishing any major project, I always feel
> **depleted**."
>
> "After finishing any major project, I always feel
> **down**."
>
> "After finishing any major project, I always feel **blue**."

From Merriam-Webster:

> **drained**: exhausted physically or emotionally
>
> **depleted**: emptied of a principal substance
>
> **down**: in a low position or place
>
> **blue**: low in spirits: melancholy

Note: One of the comments on the question mentions **depleted**.

Answer (score 0):

Not in English, but I think Torschlusspanik (German) is most fitting to your situation.  Literally translated as gate-end-panic (or gate-shut-panic), it's used to describe the anxiety that comes after reaching the end of something.

http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/__pr/GIC/TWIG__WoW/2012/09-Torschlusspanik.html

Note that this also is used to describe the panic of a situation where time is running out.  While we have sayings for the latter - behind the 8-ball, under the gun - we don't have an equivalent in English for the former.

Answer (score -1):

Such a person is **hypersensitive to natural work cycles**.  Such a person feels an amplified sense of the natural feeling of **let-down after completing a major effort**.

Imagine what it must have felt like the day after killing a mammoth.

By the way, one way of coping with this is to realize that there is a good chance of it happening again, and plan a special activity for the day after your last exam, to get you over the hump.